# $f \in \mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$ same as $f: \mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Viewing a function as an element like that confuses me a little. Is that assumption true or may the domain have a smaller dimension?

Comment: Certainly not true. There are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions in $\Bbb{N^N}$ but there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ functions $\Bbb{N^N\to N^N}$. Why is this marked as vector spaces anyway? Vector space over what field and with what structure?

Comment: Does it not mean $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, someone just answered that. I realize that this is a very basic definition but I failed to find it in my books or on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. An *element* of $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb N}$ is a *function* from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb N$, not a function from $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb N}$ into itself.